# digitalRead() function of Arduino doesn't read Input value sent by sensor after detecting the object

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, relay, digital

[image: Schematic diagram]I'm trying to turn ON the LED(inbuilt/PIN13) when photoelectric proximity sensor(12v) senses any object. Sensor is connected on pin 2. Assigned pin 2 as INPUT, I've got a 12v spdt relay for switching. 12v output from sensor is fed to coil, on the other end 5v supplied to COM pin and "Normally Open"(NO) pin to Arduino (with pull-down resistor). When 'NO' connected to loose LED it works properly (shows 5V on voltmeter when object is detected). But when connected to Arduino digitalRead(), it always returns LOW/0.

```cpp
//code
int a=0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  a ==  digitalRead(2);
  Serial.println(a);
  if(a==HIGH){
    Serial.println("Object Detected");
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);  
  }else{
    Serial.println("There's no object");  
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);  
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: it is difficult to visualize what you are describing ... please draw a schematic diagram or a wiring diagram ... also include the code that you are using

Comment: To read that detector: get rid of the relay and replace it with an ordinary voltage divider.

Comment: I tried using 7805 to get 5v output. It did not work, @SimSon

Comment: @jsotola yes. sure. I'm uploading a schematic and code.

Comment: use 1kOhm resistor for pulldown

Comment: @Juraj I used 1K resistor for pulldown, it did not work.

Comment: I'm not talking about a voltage regulator, but a simple voltage divider consisting of two resistors. The sensor is probably (do you have a datasheet?) not able to provide sufficient current to activate the relay without harm. Just don't use the relay, it's a poor design this way.

Comment: And are you sure the relay pinout is correct? Relays usually have primary contacts on one side and secondary on the other side.

Comment: @SimSon Right now I don't have appropriate value resistors to make voltage divider. It's just a relay not a relay module hence the relay pinout is correct. The sensor must be providing sufficient current(I have no datasheet) because relay switches when object is detected also on the other side of relay gets 4.96 volts (measured by multi-meter) when object is detected. But Arduino pin does not recognize change in voltage (i.e.0 to 4.96). All other stuff works absolutely fine but digitalRead() function associated with Arduino input pin returns LOW even after detecting 4.96 V.

Comment: Thank you all for replying. The problem is solved it was silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`a == digitalRead(2)` must be `a = digitalRead(2)`. You also better change the if clause to `if(a)` to avoid `true/HIGH/1` confusions.

If you had formatted the code properly, you'd have safed some time (you just need to select the code and press the `{}` button).

You also better replace the relay with a voltage divider (as I mentioned in my comment), because as long as you don't have a datasheet for the sensor you can't be sure that the sensor is designed to source that much current. If the sensor is supposed to drive a TTL logic, it will eventually fail, just like you don't drive relays with GPIOs directly. And beside that you *need a freewheeling diode across the relay coil* to deal with back EMF which will also harm the sensor.

Comment: I can't forgive myself for this. I have wasted like 3 days on this stupidest syntax typo. Thank you for drawing my attention to it. Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: oh! I'll give it a try. The freewheeling diode stuff is really helpful for me. thanks.